# Is there a way to enable password authentication such that user can log in with password or public key in azure vm?

Tags: azure, ssh, virtual-machine, config, sshd

I am trying to figure out a way to let users log into my VM using password if they do not have the correct public key. I do not want to remove public key authentication, so is there a way to enable both depending on the user?

```
# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication no

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
KbdInteractiveAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the KbdInteractiveAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via KbdInteractiveAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and KbdInteractiveAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
```

This is my sshd_config file. What changes do i make here to get what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same issue in my environment and got the below results***

*I have created the* ***linux vm*** *and connected as a root user*

[image]

*There are two ways in which we can  enable the password authentication in the* ***sshd_config file***.

```
Match user username
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

*We can add the above lines like* **`Echo "Match user username\nPasswordAuthentication yes" >> /etc/sshd/sshd_config`**

*The above command is for single user if we need multiple users* **`Match user u_name1,u_name2,....`**  *with coma separated we can add the multiple users*

*After adding the above lines we have to restart the file otherwise it won't reflect*

```
sudo systemctl restart ssh
```

*Second possible way is, I have created the new script*

```
sudo su -i
cd /usr/local/bin
vi filename.sh
```

[image]

*In that file please write the following script*

```bash
       #!/bin/bash
        
        while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
          key="$1"
          case $key in
            help)
              usage
              shift
              shift
              ;;
            -u|--user) SFTP_USER="$2"
              shift # past argument
              shift # past value
              ;;
            -p|--password) THE_PASSWORD="$2"
              shift # past argument
              shift # past value
              ;;
          esac
        done
        
        function usage {
          echo "Usage: $0 --user testuser [ --password <your password> ]" exit 0
        }
        
        if [[ -z ${SFTP_USER} ]]; then
          usage
        fi
        
        LOCAL_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(sudo grep ldap.password /opt/sftpgw/application.properties | cut -d'=' -f2)
        
        if [[ -n "$THE_PASSWORD" ]]; then
          NEW_PASSWORD="${THE_PASSWORD}"
        else
          NEW_PASSWORD=$(head /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Z0-9 | head -c 12 ; echo '')
        fi
        
        ldapmodify -D "cn=admin" -w ${LOCAL_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY} <<HERE
        dn: uid=${SFTP_USER},ou=People,dc=sftpgateway,dc=com
        changetype: modify
        replace: userPassword
        userPassword: ${NEW_PASSWORD}
        HERE
        
        echo "The password for the new user ${SFTP_USER} has been set to ${NEW_PASSWORD}"
```

*After that run the script and pass the username and password*

```
/usr/local/bin/password.sh -u <u_name> -p <password>
```

***NOTE:***
*If we don't pass the password it will generate the password*